# Kubernetes replicas correlate with API rate limit

Tags: python, kubernetes

I got an API which is providing data, I got a **ratelimit** which is for example **10requests in 60 seconds**. If the maximum of requests are reached it will throw an 429 Error.
If I **deploy** this API with only **1 Replica** set you can only do **10 requests** in 60 seconds. But if I have **two replicas** there are **20requests in 60seconds** allowed, with 3replicas 30 and so on. How can I prevent this?

I am using Kubernetes on Digital ocean and Python FastAPI and redis.

The API is running on the private image.

This is my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-server
  labels:
    app: api-server
  namespace: api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: api-server
  template:
    metadata:
      name: api-server
      labels:
        app: api-server
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: redis-stack
            image: redis/redis-stack-server:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
              - name: redis-acs-port
                containerPort: 6379
                hostPort: 6379
          - name: api-server
            image: {private_image}
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
              - name: api-access-port
                containerPort: 80
                hostPort: 80
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Comment: It depends on the purpose of your limit.  If you're trying to keep any one instance from being bogged down, then what you're doing is fine.  If you're trying to limit bandwidth, then you'll have to do the request tracking in a database shared between the instances.

Comment: Why are you scaling to multiple instances at all? Just use one instance with limited rates. In any case, you could build something like a semaphore (e.g. using a SQL DB), but that requires shared state between the microservices, which in turn makes the overall system more complex and more brittle.